# split page in two divs, when scrolling the background-color does not fill 100% height on both divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to split the page in two divs with **100% height and a background color**.

The problem starts when you scroll the page: the background-color on the second div does not fill 100% height (the second div's content is less than the other one).

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="floatleft">
      <p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p>
      <p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p>
      <p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p>
      <p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p>
    </div>
    <div class="floatright"><p>s</p><p>s</p></div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html { height: 100%; margin: 0;}

.wrap{ min-height:100%; height: 100%;}

.floatleft{background-color:red; min-height:100%;  float:left;  width: 50%; }

.floatright{background-color:yellow; float:right; min-height:100%;  width: 50%; }
```

I found similar questions on stackoverflow but no one can help me on this particular case.

Here the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jprohj09/

Comment: use display:flex approach and remove height

Comment: Could you not set a constant height than 100% everywhere? it will take the viewport height in this case. However if your left div has static contents you can work with that height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `display:flex` on the `.wrap` so the two columns have the same height . see snippet below :

or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jprohj09/7/)

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrap{ display:flex;width:100%}
.floatleft{background-color:red;  width:50%}
.floatright{background-color:yellow;width:50%  }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="floatleft">
      <p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p>
    </div>
    <div class="floatright"><p>s</p><p>s</p></div>
    <div style="clear: both;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `flexbox` model

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrap { 
  display: flex;
  min-height:100%;
}
.floatleft,
.floatright {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
}
.floatleft {background-color:red;}
.floatright{background-color:yellow;}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="floatleft">
      <p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p>
    </div>
    <div class="floatright"><p>s</p><p>s</p></div>
    <!-- you can skip this one <div style="clear: both;"> -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your issue [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jprohj09/6/). Use `display:table` for wrap.

**CSS:**

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrap{ min-height:100%; height: 100%;display: table;width: 100%;}
.floatleft{background-color:red; min-height:100%;  float:left;  width: 50%; }
.floatright{background-color:yellow; float:right; min-height:100%;  width: 50%; }
.wrap > div{    display: table-cell;float:none;}
```